# webpack splitchunks not eliminate duplicate package

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

## situation:

1. I have three packages: A, B, and C.
2. All of those packages depends on package: D.
3. And I have a project which depends on package A, B, C , and D.
4. I config my webpack in this way:

```
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: { 
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
        }                                      
      }
    }
  }
```

5. I got two files after I run **webpack** in my project, one for vendor and the one for my main app.
6. in vendor chunks, I found the D package had been duplicate for 4 times.

## question:

Is there any way to eliminate the duplication of D package in vendor chunk ?

Comment: this can happen if each of A, B, C, and your code depend on different versions of D package

Comment: They are actually depend on same versions.@amankkg

Comment: then try locking that dependency, like this https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

Comment: googling a bit led me to this tool https://github.com/FormidableLabs/inspectpack/#plugin, also it depends on npm and webpack versions, because old webpack has a dedicated dedupe plugin

Comment: @amankkg It's an awesome plugin ! I'll try it later. But I found the reason for my situation. It's because I had ran **npm link** for A, B and C. If I install A, B and C in a normal approach then everything just fine.